# Estimate of the remainder term of a complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

> Let $f(\xi)=e^{\pi i \lambda^{-1}|\xi|^2}$ and
>   $$
> f_N(\xi)=\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{(\pi i\lambda^{-1}|\xi|^2)^j}{j!}.
> $$
>   Show that there exists $C>0$ such that for *all* $\lambda >1$ and $\xi\in\mathbf{R}^d$:
>   $$
> |f(\xi)-f_N(\xi)|\leq C\frac{|\xi|^{2(N+1)}}{\lambda^{N+1}}.
> $$

This question is motivated by an attempt to understand a step in Wolff's notes on the stationary phase method. If one only needs the estimate uniformly for $\xi$ near zero, then I can see that why this is true since the higher order term of $|\xi|^{2m}$ ($m>N$) is dominated by $|\xi|^{2N+2}$. But I don't see how this is true for *all* $\xi\in\mathbf{R}^d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show this by using the integral form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem:
$$
e^{ix} = \sum_{j=0}^N\frac{(ix)^j}{j!} + \frac{i^{N+1}}{N!}\int_0^x(x-s)^Ne^{is}\,ds.
$$
From this it follows that
$$
\bigg|e^{ix}-\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{(ix)^j}{j!}\bigg| \le \frac{|x|^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}.
$$
Now substituting $x = \pi\lambda^{-1}|\xi|^2$ shows that the desired inequality holds for all $\xi\in\mathbf R^d$ and all $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: @user587192: The $i$ is crucial. Otherwise, by the reverse triangle inequality, we would have that $|e^z|$ is majorized by a polynomial of degree $N+1$ on $\mathbf C$, which is certainly not true since the exponential function restricted to the real axis grows faster than any polynomial as $\mathrm{Re}(z)\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again! I accidentally deleted my previous comment: "Is it crucial that one has the imaginary number $i$ in the exponent of $e^{ix}$? Your argument seems to suggest that the estimate would work if $i$ is not there".

Comment: @user587192 to estimate the integral you need the fact that $|e^{is}| =1$.

Comment: @JackyChong: Indeed, one nice property of $e^{ix}$ is that all the derivatives are bounded, while it is not true for $e^x$. I didn't realize that when I posted the first comment, which is now deleted.